# The short descriptions of each site when voting to close are incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

I don't know how long this bug has been around, but I just noticed that when you vote to close a question as off-topic, the short descriptions that are provided for each of the migration options are incorrect.

All of them report they are a "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers", which is the description for Stack Overflow. Each of the sites should presumably have a unique description.

[image: Short descriptions for migration sites are incorrect]

**EDIT:** Apparently this is **not an issue** on Internet Explorer 8.0. I took the above screenshot in Google Chrome (latest version—8.0), but things look fine on the same computer(s) in IE.

Comment: It's very recent. I just took [this screenshot](http://so.mrozekma.com/migrate-new-off-topic.png) less than 12 hours ago for an [unrelated post](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136/migrating-to-other-se-sites/137#137); they were right then

Comment: I can confirm that this is a universal bug.

Comment: It was [reported on Super User too](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2002/vote-to-close-off-topic-descriptions-are-wrong), but @Jarrod has tagged it as `[status-norepro]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed in the latest deploy.