# "close as off-topic" shows placeholder text instead of site description

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons

When closing a question on SO as off-topic, there's a selection of SE sites with their description. Today, the descriptions all read `Explicit description for this site`, instead of the usual elevator pitches.

This seems to manifest in Opera 11, Chromium 11, and FF 4; see a screenshot (with freehand markings - I dare not call those "circles"): [image: explicit description for this image]

Comment: I can reproduce this (on IE8 on XP, but I don't think it's a browser/OS issue) on Stack Overflow, but I cannot reproduce it on Gaming (nor here, but we don't have migration options here anyway).

Comment: @Grace Note: Aha, good point. Edited. (yes, it looks serverside, but could have been browser-related if descriptions were pulled in via some weird AJAX trickery)

Comment: You should probably wait until you actually edit before saying you edited it. ♪

Comment: good catch! Certainly server side bug in last release, will most likely be fixed quickly. :)

Comment: @Grace Note: aaargh, you're refreshing the page way too quickly.

Comment: This [has happened before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76645/the-short-descriptions-of-each-site-when-voting-to-close-are-incorrect). It must be implemented in the codebase in such a way that it can be pretty easily broken.

Comment: @cody was not the same error, Nick made bad edits to variable names, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bad attribute change when annotating our site settings earlier this morning, Description tied to Description with a Description attribute obviously boggled my mind, it's fixed now.

Comment: Yup, now showing correctly. Thanks for the quick fix!